# Indirect dependency on the framework assembly on .Net core prerelease version

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am doing some experiments with prerelase version of .Net Core.

I am using **1.0.0-preview4-004071** version of .Net Core.
Installed .NET Core SDK, created **1.0.3** folder in **C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App** and added binaries for same build version (all downloaded from **https://github.com/dotnet/cli#installers-and-binaries**).

My *.csproj file is:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
<Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\$(MSBuildToolsVersion)\Microsoft.Common.props" />

<PropertyGroup>
   <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
   <TargetFramework>netcoreapp1.1</TargetFramework>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
   <Compile Include="**\*.cs" />
   <EmbeddedResource Include="**\*.resx" />
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NETCore.App">
   <Version>1.0.3</Version>
</PackageReference>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
   <Version>1.0.0-alpha-20161104-2</Version>
   <PrivateAssets>All</PrivateAssets>
</PackageReference> 
</ItemGroup>        
<Reference Include="System.Collections.Specialized"/>
<Reference Include="System.Collections.NonGeneric">
   <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>
   <HintPath>Lib\System.Collections.NonGeneric.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
<Reference Include="System.Resources.ResourceManager"> 
   <SpecificVersion>False</SpecificVersion>  
   <HintPath>Lib\System.Resources.ResourceManager.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
</ItemGroup>
<Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
</Project>
```

Under Lib folder I have copies of DLLs from same build.

I am trying to use **System.Collections.Specialized** and **System.Collections.NonGeneric** DLLs (tried to get from default path and Lib folder) but getting warnings like this:

```
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\1.0.0-preview4-004071\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1909,5): warning MSB3268: The primary reference "System.Collections.NonGeneric" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the framework assembly "System.Runtime, Version=4.0.20.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which could not be resolved in the currently targeted framework. ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0". To resolve this problem, either remove the reference "System.Collections.NonGeneric" or retarget your application to a framework version which contains "System.Runtime, Version=4.0.20.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a". 

C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\1.0.0-preview4-004071\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(1909,5): warning MSB3268: The primary reference "System.Collections.NonGeneric" could not be resolved because it has an indirect dependency on the framework assembly "System.Diagnostics.Debug, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which could not be resolved in the currently targeted framework. ".NETFramework,Version=v4.0". To resolve this problem, either remove the reference "System.Collections.NonGeneric" or retarget your application to a framework version which contains "System.Diagnostics.Debug, Version=4.0.10.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a".
```

If I am correct problem is that msbuild can't find correct assemblies and looking into incorrect path.

How can I fix assembly path lookup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

References to .Net Core must be added as packages instead of DLLs like this:

```
<PackageReference Include="System.Reflection.Emit">
  <Version>4.0.1</Version>
</PackageReference>
```